# Flexbox justify-content depending on number of children

Tags: css, alignment, flexbox

Having this:

```
  <label>
    <button>Create</button>
  </label>
```

I want button to be aligned to the right like this

```
----------------------------
|                   [create]|
----------------------------
```

while having this:

```
  <label>
    <button>Delete</button>
    <button>Update</button>
  </label>
```

I want buttons to be in the corners

```
----------------------------
|[delete]          [update]|
----------------------------
```

Without adding additional classes to the label.

Comment: @NenadVracar provides a perfect answer IMO. If you want an explanation for how it works, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using nothing but standard flexbox properties:

- `flex-direction: row-reverse` - put the items in a row, start from "the end" (depends on reading direction)
- `justify-content: space-between` - put the items as far away from each other as possible

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <button>Create</button>
</label>

<label>
  <button>Delete</button>
  <button>Update</button>
</label>
```

Comment: I knew it is possible!

Answer (score 6):

You can just use `margin-left: auto` on `last-child` and that will produce desired result.

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
label button:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <button>Create</button>
</label>

<label>
  <button>Delete</button>
  <button>Update</button>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Flexbox `justify-content` property to align your elements.

Have a look at this **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGwMbr)**.

Or look at the code below for reference, also I've used `<div>`s in place of `<label>` as in the `.two` they are acting on both the buttons.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div:first-child {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Create</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button>Delete</button>
  <button>Update</button>
</div>
```

Learn more about [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: "Without adding additional classes to the label."

Comment: @IlyaNovojilov Oh! my bad, I've updated my answer. Please have a look.